# MySQL: case sensitivity

Tags: mysql

I have a very complicated problem. 
The dev team wrote a SQL script using jdbc (case sensitive), which searches for a table in MySQL. But in MySQL, the table is written in lower case, so it throws an error.

The problem is the dev team do not accept to change the table name to lowercase, and the exploitation team do not accept to change the table name to uppercase.

I know we can use `lower_case_table_names to 1` to force the case to insensitive, but I do not have the permission to restart mysqld.

What should I do?

Comment: This problem can only be solved internally in your company. Nothing we can do. In my opinion the current state should be adapted in any new code. This way other existing code doesn't break.

Comment: Internal problem in a company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Create view with Uppercase name 

    mysql> select * from f_val;
    ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'TEST.f_val' doesn't exist
    mysql> select * from F_VAL;
    +------+------+------+--------+-------+-------+
    | ID   | F_ID | DATE | I      | II    | III   |
    +------+------+------+--------+-------+-------+
    |    1 |   11 | 1/26 | peanut | where | Now   |
    |    2 |   22 | 1/26 | butter | he    | there |
    |    3 |   11 | 1/27 |  jelly | at    | he    |
    |    4 |   33 | 1/27 |  time  | huh   | go    |
    |    1 |   11 | 1/25 | cake   | where | Now   |
    +------+------+------+--------+-------+-------+
    5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

    CREATE VIEW f_val AS SELECT * FROM F_VAL;

select * from f_val;
+------+------+------+--------+-------+-------+
| ID   | F_ID | DATE | I      | II    | III   |
+------+------+------+--------+-------+-------+
|    1 |   11 | 1/26 | peanut | where | Now   |
|    2 |   22 | 1/26 | butter | he    | there |
|    3 |   11 | 1/27 |  jelly | at    | he    |
|    4 |   33 | 1/27 |  time  | huh   | go    |
|    1 |   11 | 1/25 | cake   | where | Now   |
+------+------+------+--------+-------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO f_val(ID,F_ID,DATE) VALUES(10,10,"1/25")
    -> ;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.08 sec)

select * from f_val;
+------+------+------+--------+-------+-------+
| ID   | F_ID | DATE | I      | II    | III   |
+------+------+------+--------+-------+-------+
|    1 |   11 | 1/26 | peanut | where | Now   |
|    2 |   22 | 1/26 | butter | he    | there |
|    3 |   11 | 1/27 |  jelly | at    | he    |
|    4 |   33 | 1/27 |  time  | huh   | go    |
|    1 |   11 | 1/25 | cake   | where | Now   |
|   10 |   10 | 1/25 | NULL   | NULL  | NULL  |
+------+------+------+--------+-------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM F_VAL;
+------+------+------+--------+-------+-------+
| ID   | F_ID | DATE | I      | II    | III   |
+------+------+------+--------+-------+-------+
|    1 |   11 | 1/26 | peanut | where | Now   |
|    2 |   22 | 1/26 | butter | he    | there |
|    3 |   11 | 1/27 |  jelly | at    | he    |
|    4 |   33 | 1/27 |  time  | huh   | go    |
|    1 |   11 | 1/25 | cake   | where | Now   |
|   10 |   10 | 1/25 | NULL   | NULL  | NULL  |
+------+------+------+--------+-------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE F_VAL;      =>   CREATE TABLE `F_VAL` (
  `ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `F_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATE` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `I` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `II` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `III` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL
)

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE f_val => CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `f_val` AS select `F_VAL`.`ID` AS `ID`,`F_VAL`.`F_ID` AS `F_ID`,`F_VAL`.`DATE` AS `DATE`,`F_VAL`.`I` AS `I`,`F_VAL`.`II` AS `II`,`F_VAL`.`III` AS `III` from `F_VAL`

Comment: added both show create tables 1st statement for original and other one for view